# Meteor simple:rest package not recognise Astronomy package methods

Tags: rest, meteor, astronomy

I'm using in my Meteor Project 'simple:rest' package and 'jagi:astronomy' package. But, simple:rest not recognise the astronomy methods.

Comment: Seems to be a relevant question. Can you please add more information like the relevant code and errors / expected vs. actual behavior related to the code.